# remove line from array by key

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: How to remove specific element from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448964/php-how-to-remove-specific-element-from-an-array)

How can i remove a line from an array where the key name = a given target...such as

```
[name] => super [price] => 65.87 [quantity] => 25 [addtocart] => 1
```

say i wanted to remove the `[addtocart] => 1` part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want to `unset($arr['addtocart']);`

Comment: @meder - sorry for the retarded edit, don't know where my brain was at.

Comment: @karim79 - no problem, I do it all the time... its late too
@Patrick - yeah - that's it.

Comment: @karim79 - thanks for giving me my first cleanup badge :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$vars = array('name' => super, 'price' => 65.87, 'quantity' => 25, 'addtocart' => 1);

unset($vars['addtocart']);
```