# delete elements in an array and adjust index

Tags: php

Is there a way in php to remove elements in an array and then reindex the remaining elements? For example, here is what I want to do. In an array,

```
$a = array("a","b","c");
```

I want to delete element "b", I used unset() to do that leaving the array like ("a",null,"c"). What I really want is make the array ("a","c") after deleting "b". How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217721/how-to-remove-array-element-and-then-re-index-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unset` does not create null elements in your array. The array will be one element smaller than before.

If you want to reindex the array after removing an element, use `$array = array_values($array);`.

Answer (score 1):

do you want to do something like

```
 $new_array = array_filter($a)
```

? You can read about [array filter function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and take a look at the case without callback parameter (as in my example)

Comment: Thanks, I need filter incorporating with array_values() function.

Answer (score 0):

```
unset($a[1]);
$a = array_values($a);
```