# How to delete element from array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have done a lot of researching, and I cant find out how to delete an element from an array in PHP. In Java, if you have an `ArrayList<SomeObject> list`, you would say `list.remove(someObject);`.

Is there anything similar you can do in PHP? I have found `unset($array[$index]);`, but it doesnt seem to work.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Define **`doesnt seem to work`**

Comment: `unset` is correct. How have you determined that it doesn't work?

Comment: Unset works but maybe your index is an int and the index you use for unsetting is a string?

Comment: I'll define doesnt seem to work: When you use unset, I have read that the array doesnt get "reindexed". Then I used array_values($array); , but im not sure about if thats working either.

Comment: @Nir - my index is an int, just tried it now

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217721/how-to-remove-array-element-and-then-re-index-array

Comment: @chumkiu - That seemt to be exactly what I need! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`unset($array[$index]);` actually works.
The only issue I can think of is the way you're iterating this array.
just use `foreach` instead of `for`

also make sure that $index contains correct value

to test your array you can use `var_dump()`:

```
$cars[0]="Volvo"; 
$cars[1]="BMW"; 
$cars[2]="Toyota"; 

unset($cars[0]);
var_dump($cars);
```

Comment: Lets say i have this array $cars[0]="Volvo"; $cars[1]="BMW"; $cars[2]="Toyota"; When i say unset($cars[0]), I only have [1] and [2] remaining, right?

Answer (score 1):

`unset` should work, you can also try this:

```
$array = array_merge(
             array_slice($array, 0, $index),
             array_slice($array, $index+1)
         );
```

Comment: slices array into 2 subarrays without the element that you want to remove and then merges them into one

Answer (score 1):

You need to either remove it and remove the empty array:

```
function remove_empty($ar){
    $aar = array();
    while(list($key, $val) = each($ar)){
        if (is_array($val)){
            $val = remove_empty($val);
            if (count($val)!=0){
                $aar[$key] = $val;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (trim($val) != ""){
                $aar[$key] = $val;
            }
        }
    }
    unset($ar);
    return $aar;
}
```

remove_empty(array(1,2,3, '', 5)) returns array(1,2,3,5)

Comment: So if I have [1], [2], [3], [4], and i remove [2], i want the array to reindex the array, so instead of [1], [3], [4], i get [1], [2], [3]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete just one array element you can use `unset()` or alternative `array_splice()`

**Unset()**
Example :

**Code**

```
<?php

    $array = array(0 => "x", 1 => "y", 2 => "z");
    unset($array[1]);
    //If you want to delete the second index ie, array[1]
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array (
    [0] => a
    [2] => c
)
```