# Modify array contents

Tags: php, arrays

I've used

```
unset($quotes_array[0]['methods'][0]);
$quotes_array[0]['methods'] = array_values($quotes_array[0]['methods']);
```

to remove the first element of an array, but the selection form where the array is used no longer responds correctly to the radio button selected by the user.
The original array looked like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => advshipper
        [methods] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1-0-0
                        [title] => Trade Shipping
                        [cost] => 20
                        [icon] => 
                        [shipping_ts] => 
                        [quote_i] => 0
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2-0-0
                        [title] => 1-2 working days
                        [cost] => 3.2916666666667
                        [icon] => 
                        [shipping_ts] => 
                        [quote_i] => 1
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 4-0-0
                        [title] => 2-3 working days
                        [cost] => 2.4916666666667
                        [icon] => 
                        [shipping_ts] => 
                        [quote_i] => 2
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 8-0-0
                        [title] => Click & Collect
                        [cost] => 0
                        [icon] => 
                        [shipping_ts] => 
                        [quote_i] => 3
                    )

            )

        [module] => Shipping
        [tax] => 20
    )

)
```

And the modified array looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => advshipper
        [methods] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2-0-0
                        [title] => 1-2 working days
                        [cost] => 3.2916666666667
                        [icon] => 
                        [shipping_ts] => 
                        [quote_i] => 1
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 4-0-0
                        [title] => 2-3 working days
                        [cost] => 2.4916666666667
                        [icon] => 
                        [shipping_ts] => 
                        [quote_i] => 2
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 8-0-0
                        [title] => Click & Collect
                        [cost] => 0
                        [icon] => 
                        [shipping_ts] => 
                        [quote_i] => 3
                    )

            )

        [module] => Shipping
        [tax] => 20
    )

)
```

I suspect the problem is caused by the fact that in the modified array, [quote_i] now starts at 1, and not 0 as in the original. So i have [quote_i] as 1, 2 then 3 but it should be 0, 1, then 2.

I've tried using array_walk to correct this, but not been successful.

Any suggestions on a solution to this?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217721/how-to-remove-array-element-and-then-re-index-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick basically would be to correct `quote_i`

```
$counter = 0;
foreach ($quotes_array[0]['methods'] as $key => $value)
{
    $quotes_array[0]['methods'][$key]['quote_i'] = $counter;
    $counter++;
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Doing it this way will correct ['quote_i'] however many there are in the array. Thanks. Another day where i've learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

Using array_walk with example code that should match your use case

```
<?php
foreach ($quotes_array[0]['methods'] as $a) {
    $a = array(
        array('quote_i' => 1),
        array('quote_i' => 2),
        array('quote_i' => 3)
        );

    array_walk($a, function(&$item, $key) {
        $item['quote_i'] = $item['quote_i'] - 1;
    });

    var_dump($a);

    // array([0] => array('quote_i' => 0), [1] => array('quote_i' => 1), [2] => array('quote_id' => 2))
}
```