# After deleting the particular multidimensional array element in PHP, the Next array elements are not positioning automatically

Tags: php, cakephp, multidimensional-array, reference

I've created the multidimensional array in the following format

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 10 [quantity] => 3 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 9 [quantity] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 12 [quantity] => 4 ) )
```

When I try to unset an particular array element based on id, after unset i'm getting the array like below.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 10 [quantity] => 3 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 12 [quantity] => 4 ) )
```

The array element is getting unset, but the next array element doesn't move to the deleted array position.

For unset an array element, I'm using the following code.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($cartdetails["products"] as $key => $item){
    if ($item['id'] == $id) {
        $match = true;
        break;
    }
    $i++;
}
if($match == 'true'){
    unset($cartdetails['products'][$i]);
}
```

How to solve this issue? Please kindly help me to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Arrays have fixed positions. You'll need to move them manually in case you want to.

Comment: Please check this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217721/how-to-remove-array-element-and-then-re-index-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want to maintain order, but just want to re-index the keys, you can use the [array_values()](https://www.php.net/array_values) function.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($cartdetails["products"] as $key => $item){
    if ($item['id'] == $id) {
        $match = true;
        break;
    }
    $i++;
}
if($match == 'true'){
    unset($cartdetails['products'][$i]);
}
array_values($cartdetails['products']);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 

I've tried what you've mentioned above. But its not working..

Comment: Its Working fine.. After assigning like
    `$cartdetails['products'] = array_values($cartdetails['products']);`

Answer (score 0):

Using unset doesn't alter the indexing of the Array. You probably want to use array_splice.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use this???

```
$id = 9;
foreach($cartdetails["products"] as $key => $item){
   if ($item['id'] == $id) {
       unset($cartdetails['products'][$key]);
       break;
   }    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use $i++ to find an element to unset?

You can unset your element inside foreach loop:

```
foreach($cartdetails['products'] as $key => $item){
    if ($item['id'] == $id) {
        unset($cartdetails['products'][$key]);
        break;
    }
}
// in your case array_values will "reindex" your array
array_values($cartdetails['products']);
```