# PHP remove Item in array and reset key

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, removechild

I have a big array (multidimensional) and I need to remove items in it and reset the index for it. I have no idea how to do it.

Example:

```
$array = array(
 0 => 'Name G',
 1 => 'Name Z',
 2 => 'Name A',
 3 => 'Name H',
 4 => 'Name U',
)
```

I need this:

```
$array = array(
 0 => 'Name G',
 1 => 'Name A',
 2 => 'Name U',
)
```

I can do the unset() fine .. but I have this:

```
$array = array(
 0 => 'Name G',
 2 => 'Name A',
 4 => 'Name U',
)
```

**I Can't SORT it**

Is there a php function that will do this? else How can I do it?

Comment: This doesn't look like valid arrays. This will give you a syntax error.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen yes sorry, I have multiple arrays in arrays in objects ... bad copy and paste

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Remove Array Element and Then Re-Index Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217721/how-to-remove-array-element-and-then-re-index-array)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$array = array(
    0 => 'Name G',
    1 => 'Name Z',
    2 => 'Name A',
    3 => 'Name H',
    4 => 'Name U',
);

unset($array[1]);
unset($array[3]);
$array = array_values($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

you asked 2 questions here i think.  either way, if you are trying to re-index the keys use array_values

```
 $new_array = array_values($array);
 print_r($new_array);
```

result:

```
 Array
 (
[0] => Name G
[1] => Name A
[2] => Name U
 )
```