# Removing a particular index/item from session array in Laravel

Tags: php, session, laravel

I have a Controller that adds a name of a university class to the session:

```
    // Get all requests
    $data = $request->all();

    .. input validation here ..

    // Push the class to the session
    Session::push('class', $data['class']);
```

This generates a nice to use array like this:

```
["ECEC 301 Advanced Programming for Engineers Lab","ECEC 301 Advanced Programming for Engineers Lecture"]
```

I also have this code that checks for duplicates like this:

```
    // Ensures no duplicate entries in the session
    if(Session::has('class')) {
        foreach(Session::get('class') as $class) {
            if($data['class'] === $class) {
                return Response::json(array(
                        'success' => false,
                        'code' => 0,
                        'message' => $data['class'] . ' already in the cart'
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

My question is - how do I remove a particular class from the session?

This is what I have:

```
    // Remove the item [if exists]
    if(Session::has('class')) {
        foreach(Session::get('class') as $class) {
            if($data['class'] === $class) {
                Session::pull('class', $data['class']);
                return Response::json(array(
                        'success' => true,
                        'code' => 1,
                        'message' => $data['class'] . ' removed from cart'
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

However, this seems to remove *everything* from the cart instead of just `ECEC 301 Advanced Programming for Engineers Lab`, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, I used `unset` and `array_values` from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5217738/1913389):

```
    // Remove the item [if exists]
    if(Session::has('class')) {
        $classes = Session::get('class');
        foreach($classes as $index => $class) {
            if($data['class'] === $class) {
                unset($classes[$index]);
                $newClass = array_values($classes);
                Session::put('class', $newClass);
                return Response::json(array(
                        'success' => true,
                        'code' => 1,
                        'class' => $classes,
                        'message' => $data['class'] . ' removed from cart'
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So why not vote to close this post as a duplicate then?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `Session::pull` in a wrong way. `Session::pull(a,b)` pulls `a` from the session and removes it from the session. If `a` is not found in the session, then `b` is returned as a default value. Note that `b` is optional.

In order to replace the `class` value, you can just use

```
Session::put('class', $data['class']);
```

This will overwrite the old `class` value in the session.

**Edit**

I would advise you to rename the session key `class` to `classes`, as this key may contain multiple classes.

I would also advise to work with key => value pairs in the array, instead of with only values and implicit keys. This will allow you to easily delete a class from the classes array and store the new classes array in the session using the `put` method. It will also make it a lot easier to work with the selected classes in the backend and in the database.

Comment: Wouldn't this overwrite the entire `class` array? Let's say I have `["ECEC 301 Advanced Programming for Engineers Lab","ECEC 301 Advanced Programming for Engineers Lecture"]
`, and I use `put`, it will replace the entire array I have above, instead of selectively removing one.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I misinterpreted your code and have made some suggestions in the edited answer. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this tomorrow as I am going to bed. I'll come back to give you comments or mark as answer!

Comment: Your solution replaced everything of that key instead. I used `unset` and `array_values` to unset and re-index the values.