# Misunderstanding of array_values

Tags: php, php-7, php-7.2

I've a problem to unerstand correctly array_values, when I do:

```
$array[] = 'data1'; // I want [0 => 'data1']
unset($array[0]); // I want []
$array = array_values($array); // I want [] but keys resetted
$array[] = 'data2'; // I want [0 => 'data2']
$array[] = 'data3'; // I want [0 => 'data2', 1 => 'data3']
dump($array);
```

I've the result:

```
array:2 [▼
  1 => "data2"
  2 => "data3"
]
```

But I'll want:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "data2"
  1 => "data3"
]
```

Maybe someone can explain it to me ? Because I'm a little lost :-/

For exemple, if I've an array with 10 values in, remove the 3rd value, and do an `array_values` on, it works well.

But if I remove the last value from an array, then when I do a array_value, the next value I add, always have id 1 and not 0.

Comment: `unset($array[0]);` you have unset the `0` index.

Comment: This has been answered before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217721/how-to-remove-array-element-and-then-re-index-array

Comment: @DragonZero I use array_values... But if the array is empty, it not work... If I've an array with 3 values, I remove the 2nd and do a array_values, keyes are redistributed correctly, but if array is empty, it do nothing...

Comment: declare the array before utilizing it `$array = array();`

Comment: Interesting. That may even qualify as a bug in PHP.

Comment: @Sheppard The code you have returns with the correct indexes for me, I think I don't understand your question. https://eval.in/915447

Comment: @pokeybit I've exactly the same issue if I declare it before...

Comment: @Sheppard  Simple check to see if the array has any values use: if (count($array) > 0) { /*do work*/ }

Comment: @DragonZero it return me 0 before and after array_values

Comment: Clearly a behavioural difference between versions: https://3v4l.org/auHLM. Might want to consider filing a [bug report](http://bugs.php.net).

Comment: @deceze, I agree, quite a difference.

Comment: bug is what? `array_values` or `unset` ?

Comment: @KresimirPendic array_values bug, it doesn't work when the array is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour has been already reported as a bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75433 and (apparently as the result of this post) also: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75653