# PHP - Deleting an element of a JSON array changes the array syntax

Tags: php, arrays, json, element

I can successfully delete elements of a JSON array with PHP, but I cannot understand why the JSON array changes syntax after deleting an element that's not the last one.

So, here's my `User.json` file:

```
[ 
    {
        "id": "kS79BhPx"
    },
    {
        "id": "ycC7km7A"
    },
    {
        "id": "hgF5D4es"
    }
]
```

Here's my `delete.php` script:

```
$className = "Users";

// get the index
$index = (int)$_GET['index'];

//fetch data from json
$data = file_get_contents($className. '.json');
$data_array = json_decode($data, true);

// delete the row with the index
unset($data_array[$index]);

//encode back to json
$data = json_encode($data_array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
file_put_contents($className. '.json', $data);
```

So, if I go to the following URL, just to test my php function:

```
https://example.com/delete.php?index=0
```

The script successfully deletes the first element of the JSON array, but then it changes into this:

```
{
    "1": {
        "id": "ycC7km7A"
    },
    "2": {
        "id": "hgF5D4es"
    }
}
```

Instead, if I set `https://example.com/delete.php?index=2` - so I want to delete the last array's element - it saves it as follows:

```
[
    {
        "id": "kS79BhPx"
    },
    {
        "id": "ycC7km7A"
    }
]
```

This last result is what I need to achieve all the times I delete an element because I need the JSON array syntax to stay as `[...]`, not as `{...}`.

What am I doing wrong in my PHP script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `unset()` on an array (associative or not) in PHP will preserve the existing keys making the array associative. You need to [reindex the array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5217738/1456201) after using `unset()`:

```php
// delete the row with the index
unset($data_array[$index]);
$data_array = array_values($data_array);
```