# php remove key on $_POST

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: How to remove specific element from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448964/php-how-to-remove-specific-element-from-an-array)

Here in my $_POST, I am quite confused on how to trim or drop the key 'submit'. I'm quite confused with this array manipulation. Thanks.

```
Array
(
    [Physical_Education] => 43
    [Statistics] => 34
    [Biology] => 43
    [Math] => 34
    [quarter] => 1
    [submit] => Submit Grades
)
```

Comment: Why do you need to remove the key anyways?

Comment: The `$_POST` array itself isn't really meant to be manipulated. Any information you get from it should be taken out of the array and put into variables or another array; it's better coding practice.

Comment: What is so weird about unsetting properties in an associative array? JavaScript dedicates a whole keyword to it (`delete`) - ah but yes, `$_POST` is a global thing, don't mess with it too much.

Comment: Thanks for the insights about this.

Comment: i'm so confused as to why it even includes submit buttons and their values lol

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using [`unset()`](http://php.net/unset) should do the trick:

```
unset($_POST['submit']);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can `unset()` the member, like [Tim Cooper suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8440039/31671).

However, if you don't want that being POST'd in the first place, you could drop the `name` attribute on your submit button.

Answer (score 1):

Tackle the root of the problem!

It's in there because your submit button looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Grades">
```

Thus, remove the `name` and it won't be sent:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Grades">
```