# Remove all elements in array matching a specific string using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm hoping this is really simple, and I'm missing something obvious!

I'm trying to remove all elements in an array that match a certain string. It's a basic 1D array.

```
array("Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Remove", "Remove");
```

I want to end up with

```
array("Value1", "Value2", "Value3");
```

Why does `array_filter($array, "Remove");` not work?

Thanks.

Comment: Because you're using it incorrectly. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php see examples.

Comment: It accepts a callback.  `array_filter($array, function($a) {return $a !== "Remove";});`

Comment: I understand the examples use functions, but I don't understand what they are returning? Is there not a simple way to do it without building a handler function?

Comment: @CraigWilson The simpler way is with a PHP 5.3+ anonymous function as in my comment above.

Comment: simple, yes, magic not requiring you to  do anything - no.

Comment: @CraigWilson they return true or false... if its true, the item stays. If its false, it gets removed.

Comment: @CraigWilson check my answer for illustration

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thanks for the reply. I feel Mario's solution is much cleaner though. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: How to remove specific element from an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448964/php-how-to-remove-specific-element-from-an-array)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can just use [`array_diff`](http://php.net/array_diff) here, if it's one fixed string:

```
$array = array_diff($array, array("Remove"));
```

For more complex matching, I'd use [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/preg_grep) obviously:

```
$array = preg_grep("/^Remove$/i", $array, PREG_GREP_INVERT);
// matches upper and lowercase for example
```

Comment: Regular expressions are *usually* slower for large data-set.

Comment: @shiplu For small data sets moreso. The regex compilation is done just once. Which is where the overhead is. PCRE is oftentimes faster for string processing, in this case possibly also the array processing, as most of it operates in C, not as PHP bytecode in the Zend VM.

Comment: Tip: You probably want to use `$array = array_values($array);` for reindexing, right after `array_diff` to not run into PHP error warnings of undefined array indices.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use a callback.

```
array_filter($array, function($e){
   return stripos("Remove", $e)===false
});
```

To understand above code properly see this commented code.

```
array_filter($array, function($e){
    if(stripos("Remove", $e)===false) // "Remove" is not found
        return true; // true to keep it.
    else
        return false; // false to filter it. 
});
```

Comment: The tutorial is appreciated!  My IDE complained, so I added a semi-colon:  `return stripos("Remove", $e)===false;`