# Removing first dimension element if second dimension value is repeated

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Say I have an array like this

```
$posts = array(
     array('post_title'=>10, 'post_id'=>1), 
     array('post_title'=>11, 'post_id'=>2),
     array('post_title'=>12, 'post_id'=>3), 
     array('post_title'=>13, 'post_id'=>4),
     array('post_title'=>10, 'post_id'=>5)
);
```

How can I remove the first dimensional element if one of its 'post_title' or 'post_id' value is repeated?

Example:

Suppose we know that 'post_title' is '10' in two first dimensional elements.

How can I remove the repeated element from $posts?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: How to remove specific element from an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448964/php-how-to-remove-specific-element-from-an-array)

Comment: What if we don´t know which value is repeated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new array where you will store these `post_title` values. loop through `$posts` array and unset any duplicates. Example:

```
$posts = array(
     array('post_title'=>10, 'post_id'=>1), 
     array('post_title'=>11, 'post_id'=>2),
     array('post_title'=>12, 'post_id'=>3), 
     array('post_title'=>13, 'post_id'=>4),
     array('post_title'=>10, 'post_id'=>5)
);

$tmp_array = array();
foreach ($posts as $i => $post)
{
    if (!in_array($post['post_title'], $tmp_array)) // if it doesn't exist, store it
    {
        $tmp_array[] = $post['post_title'];
    } else { // element exists, delete it
        unset($posts[$i]);
    }
}
```

Now in your `$posts` array you will have unique `post_title` values.

Comment: You could do it with `for` loop as well, I just found it more suitable at that moment.