# how do I remove some keys of a multiple array?

Tags: php, arrays

i have a multiple array that looks like this :

```
$name_array = [
            ['name' => 'mike', 'number' => (int)$a],
            ['name' => 'lisa', 'number' => (int)$b],
            ['name' => 'michelle','number' => (int)$c],
];
```

now I want to remove all the keys where 'number' is 0

i tried it like this:

```
 foreach ( $name_array as $key => $val )
        {
            if ( $val['number'] == 0 )
            {
                unset($name_array[$key][$val['number']]);
            }
        }
```

but this just dont work... could someone help me with this?

$a and $c are == 0 - so I want to delete them

thanks for any help :)

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448964/php-how-to-remove-specific-element-from-an-array

Answer (score 0):

You are not overwriting the same error. use this code :

```
$a = 0;
$b = 200;
$c = 0;

$name_array = [
    ['name' => 'mike', 'number' => (int) $a],
    ['name' => 'lisa', 'number' => (int) $b],
    ['name' => 'michelle', 'number' => (int) $c],
];

for ($i=0; $i<count($name_array); $i++){
    if(!$name_array[$i]['number']){
        unset($name_array[$i]['number']);
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_R($name_array);
```

//Sample output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => mike
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => lisa
            [number] => 200
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => michelle
        )

)
```

Comment: i dont know why but this wont work :o i think its about the $name_array[$i]['number'] --- the first [] is just filled with names - so why there shoult be the $i?

Comment: Because without using indexes, how will you override the keys or unset the keys? i think foreach doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide me the values of $a,$b,$c. so i can test my code again

Comment: or maybe because of the count($name_array) - it shouldnt count anything in there? it should just search for any key where 'number' is 0 :o

Comment: $a = 0, $b= 20, $c= 0 ---- $a and $b should be removed cause there 'number' - index is 0 :)

Comment: Wth the values provided, my code is working perfect for me.

Comment: well this worked better.. the strange thing is, it havent removed both 0 - it just removed the first one :o 

( the orginal code have about 30 times a 0 and your code have removed 29 of it :o )

Comment: i mean that $a and $c are both 0.. and your code just removed $a - but $c is still in the output :)

Comment: See inside my output code in the answer. it also removed the $c.  i think you are not executing my code properly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
<?php 

$a = 0;
$b = 0;
$c = 10;
$name_array = [
    ['name' => 'mike', 'number' => (int) $a],
    ['name' => 'lisa', 'number' => (int) $b],
    ['name' => 'michelle', 'number' => (int) $c],
];

for ($i=0; $i<count($name_array); $i++){
    if($name_array[$i]['number']==0){
        //unset($name_array[$i]['number']);
        unset($name_array[$i]);
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_R($name_array);

?>
```

Comment: this wouldnt unset just the keys where 'number' is 0 :o

Comment: this have removed every 0, beside the last one :o my orginal code have 30 times a 0 and it removed just 29 o.o

Answer (score 0):

You were very nearly there with your original effort but the syntax to access the number element of the array was incorrect. This does work as you expect.

```
$a=0; 
$b=99;
$c=0;


$name_array = array(
    array( 'name' => 'mike',    'number' => (int)$a ),
    array( 'name' => 'lisa',    'number' => (int)$b ),
    array( 'name' => 'michelle','number' => (int)$c ),
);

foreach ( $name_array as $key => $val ) {
    if ( $val['number'] === 0 ) unset( $name_array[$key]['number'] );
}
```

Comment: this just removes all the 0, beside the last one :o

Comment: that is what you wanted was it not?  `"now I want to remove all the keys where 'number' is 0 "`

Answer (score 0):

Removing unwanted items from arrays sounds like a good use of [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

```
$name_array = array_filter($name_array, function($x){
    return $x['number'] != 0;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

change

```
unset($key);
```

to

```
unset($name_array[$key]['number']);
```