# Remove particular elements from an array using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have one array like below

```
Array
    (
        [AllocationPool] => TEST do not USE
        [Quarter] => 2016-Q4
        [Segment] => Storage
        [Region] => 
        [SubRegion] => 
        [Country] => 
        [typeofrec] => 0
        [TotalAllocations] => 100
        [TotalTransfersOut] => 75
        [TotalTransfersIn] => 0
        [StartOfAllocation] => 25
        [ApprovedActivities] => 0
        [AvailableBalance] => 25
        [TotalApprovedClaims] => 0
        [Balance] => 25
        [TotalUnApprovedClaims] => 0
        [Exposure] => 25
    )
```

I need to remove some elements from this array and formatted to new structure.

I need to change below structure after format my array

```
Array
    (
        [AllocationPool] => TEST do not USE
        [Quarter] => 2016-Q4
        [Segment] => Storage
        [Region] => 
        [SubRegion] => 
        [Country] => 
    )
```

Is any method available in php for remove some elements in an array using php?

Comment: Just delete the variables using [unset](http://php.net/unset), `unset($arr['Country'])` will remove Country from the array.

Comment: You really ought to create an array of keys you wish to end up with, rather than unsetting each unwanted one. What if more keys are passed in future?

Comment: Would be nice if you could show what you already tried

Comment: My example: `foreach($keys as $key){ $new_array[$key] = $bad_array[$key]; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unset the variables  of array using `unset()`

```
unset($array[typeofrec]);
unset($array[TotalAllocations]);
unset($array[TotalTransfersOut]);
unset($array[TotalTransfersIn]);
unset($array[ApprovedActivities]);
unset($array[AvailableBalance]);
unset($array[TotalApprovedClaims]);
unset($array[Balance]);
unset($array[TotalUnApprovedClaims]);
unset($array[Exposure]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove a particular element from an array use **unset()**.

```
unset($array[typeofrec]);
unset($array[TotalAllocations]);
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_search](http://php.net/array_search) to get the key and remove it with unset if found:

```
if (($key = array_search('strawberry', $array)) !== false) {
    unset($array[$key]); // This will remove the element
}
```

Here is some more ideas [PHP: How to remove specific element from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448964/php-how-to-remove-specific-element-from-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods which can be used to remove array elements: `unset()`, `array_filter`, `array_reduce`.

One possible way to do it would be:

```
$myArray = array_filter($myArray, function ($key) {
    return in_array($key, array('AllocationPool', 'Quarter', 'Segment', 'Region', 'SubRegion', 'Country'));
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

Answer (score 0):

try for each key

> unset( $arr["key"] )

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

assuming your array is $arr, do

> unset( $arr["TotalAllocations"] ); ...

if you want to keep some consecutive values, you may use slice()

> $output = array_slice($input, 0, 6);  // keep first 6 values

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at `array_filter($array, $callback, $flag)` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). With this function you can filter (remove) elements from the array. If you only provide the array parameter the function will remove all the values equal to `FALSE` from the array. And if you want, you can provide a callback function to perform a more sophisticated filter, if the callback returns false, then the given item will be filter from the array.