# deleting elements from array containing specific string keywords

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-replace

i have an array **$link** which contains some links inside it and i wanna delete all the links which are from sites present in **$Blocklinks**

```
 $links=array(
'http://ckfht.ca/sultan/files/2016/',
'http://dl1.uploadplus.net/dl2/2016/Sultan.2016/',
'http://www.google.com',
'http://subindomovie.xyz/film/indexof-sultan-720p'
'http://subindomovie.xyz/film/sultan-720-p'
'http://www.liveaccountbook.com/sultan/'


);

$Blocklinks=array(
    'subindomovie.xyz',
    'www.liveaccountbook.com'
);
  /* remove urls containing link from $Blocklinks .. What should i do here??*/
$links=deletelinks($links,$Blocklinks);

/*  output */
print_r($links);

output I want
------
Array
(
    [0] => http://ckfht.ca/sultan/files/2016/
    [1] => http://dl1.uploadplus.net/dl2/2016/Sultan.2016/
    [2] => http://www.google.com
)
```

Comment: what have your tried? What error messages did you get? If no error messages where displayed then please post your php error log. Thank You

Comment: you can check if a string contains a specific substring by using the [strpos function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php). Also use foreach loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: How to remove specific element from an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448964/php-how-to-remove-specific-element-from-an-array)

Comment: "i have'nt tried any function".  The order of using this site is 1.) Try something.  2.) Have trouble getting it to work.  3.) Ask a question.  We are not here to fulfill your project requirements for you

Comment: So do some basic searching. Start with finding out how to iterate through an array.  Then find out how to match part of one string with all of another string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you need is to filter urls by hostname, you can do it this way:

```
$result = array_filter($links, function ($i) use ($Blocklinks) {
    return !in_array(parse_url($i, PHP_URL_HOST), $Blocklinks); });
```

---

If you want to replace urls with an empty string:

functional way:

```
$result = array_map(function ($i) use ($Blocklinks) {
    return in_array(parse_url($i, PHP_URL_HOST), $Blocklinks) ? '' : $i;
}, $links);
```

procedural way:

```
$result = [];
foreach($links as $link) {
    $result = in_array(parse_url($link, PHP_URL_HOST), $Blocklinks) ? '' : $link;
}
```

Comment: and what if i want to make them blank instead of removing them, what should i do then?

Comment: @Kaif: To do that `array_map` is better fitted. But `array_map` as `array_filter` is only the functional version of a simple `foreach` loop where you store modified or selected items in a new array.

Comment: Awesome!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! :D

Answer (score 1):

```
$links = array_filter($links, function ($link) use ($Blocklinks) {
    foreach ($Blocklinks as $block) {
        if (strstr($link, $block) !== false) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your `deletelinks()` function...

```
function deletelinks($links,$Blocklinks)
{
    foreach($links as $key => $link)
    {
        foreach($Blocklinks as $bLink)
        {
            if (strpos($link,$bLink) !== false) {
                unset($links[$key]); 
            }   
        }
    }
    return $links;
}
```

This will return you :

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://ckfht.ca/sultan/files/2016/
    [1] => http://dl1.uploadplus.net/dl2/2016/Sultan.2016/
    [2] => http://www.google.com
)
```

**LIVE EXAMPLE : [CLICK HERE](https://eval.in/624966)**

Comment: @Kaif welcome dear, you can vote the answer which is helpful for you...

Answer (score 0):

> Seems like you were thinking along the lines of a function that would delete the links hence the `deletelinks($links, $Blocklinks)`. Perhaps the function below comes in handy... You may as well [try it out here](https://eval.in/624991).

```
<?php

    $links      = array(
                'http://ckfht.ca/sultan/files/2016/',
                'http://dl1.uploadplus.net/dl2/2016/Sultan.2016/',
                'http://www.google.com',
                'http://subindomovie.xyz/film/indexof-sultan-720p',
                'http://subindomovie.xyz/film/sultan-720-p',
                'http://www.liveaccountbook.com/sultan/',
                );

    $blockLinks = array(
                'subindomovie.xyz',
                'www.liveaccountbook.com',
    );

    $newLinks   = deleteLinks($links, $blockLinks);
    var_dump($newLinks);

    function deleteLinks($links, $blockLinks){
        foreach($links as $key=>$link){
            foreach($blockLinks as $index=>$blockLink){
                if(stristr($link, $blockLink)){
                    unset($links[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
        return $links;
    }

    // THE var_dump($newLinks) ABOVE WOULD PRODUCE SOMETHING LIKE:

    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'http://ckfht.ca/sultan/files/2016/' (length=34)
      1 => string 'http://dl1.uploadplus.net/dl2/2016/Sultan.2016/' (length=47)
      2 => string 'http://www.google.com' (length=21)
```