# Copy and modify array

Tags: php

I'm not experienced with PHP and have to redact the password in the following code:

```
    $body=array(
        'userInfo' => array(
            'userName' => $username,
            'password' => $password,
            'applicationKey' => $appKey,
        ),
    );
```

The variable `$body` is used both in application logic, and in logging the array:

```
$this->logger->debug("REQUEST: URL[{$this->config->endpoint}] BODY: " . json_encode($body));
```

But I should not be logging the password. I'd like to redact it.

I know I could just copy and paste the array to a new variable `$body_with_password_hidden` but I'd like to learn some PHP idioms, not to mention keep the code base as compact as realistically possible.

What would be an elegant way to do this? In a language I am more comfortable, I would clone the dictionary, and overwrite the sensitive value. How would I do this in PHP?

### More info

Current log statement:

```
[2018-04-10T18:23:11+00:00] [DEBUG] REQUEST: URL[http://myservice.com/myendpoint/login] BODY: {"userInfo":{"userName":"Administrator","password":"Administrator","applicationKey":"abc123"}} -
```

Desired log statement:

```
[2018-04-10T18:23:11+00:00] [DEBUG] REQUEST: URL[http://myservice.com/myendpoint/login] BODY: {"userInfo":{"userName":"Administrator","password":"********","applicationKey":"abc123"}} -
```

Comment: Same as you said - clone value and remove key.

Comment: $body['userInfo']['password'] = ''; should do the trick.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: How to remove specific element from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448964/php-how-to-remove-specific-element-from-an-array)

Comment: Read about [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). The answer to your question can be found on the ["accessing with square brackets syntax" section](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a template that matches the structure of your data, with your desired redaction symbol as a value for the appropriate key.

```
$redacted = ['userInfo' => ['password' => '********']];
```

Then use `array_replace_recursive` to overwrite the value in the original data when you log it.

```
$this->logger->debug(
    "REQUEST: URL[{$this->config->endpoint}] BODY: "
    . json_encode(array_replace_recursive($body, $redacted))
);
```

This may be kind of overkill for overwriting a single value, but could be a neater way of doing it if you ever have a more complex structure with more values that need to be replaced.

Comment: Thank you. That's the kind of neat trick I was hoping to learn.

Answer (score 4):

You can override this value directly:

```
$body['userInfo']['password'] = null;
```

or just remove a whole key:

```
unset($body['userInfo']['password']);
```

Comment: You’d need to make a copy of the array, or do logging only after using the password in the business logic, hence my preference for the other solution. But thank you still.

Answer (score 1):

You can just pop a value into the array, based on the key's name. So you have the following:

```
$body=array(
        'userInfo' => array(
            'userName' => $username,
            'password' => $password,
            'applicationKey' => $appKey,
        ),
    );
```

You could then do:

```
$body['userInfo']['password'] = null;
```

And that would set the key within userInfo to a null value.

Comment: The key will still be set to `password`, but the value will be null

Comment: Which is fine, according to the OP's desired output syntax :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the shortest way would be the make a copy of the array, and log it with the modified `password` value.

```
$body_with_password_hidden = $body;
$body_with_password_hidden['userInfo']['password'] = "********";
```

Then log the `$body_with_password_hidden`

Answer (score 0):

I built a package to do this very thing. It's pretty easy to use. https://github.com/mtownsend5512/array-redactor

```
$body = (new \Mtownsend\ArrayRedactor\ArrayRedactor(array(
    'userInfo' => array(
        'userName' => $username,
        'password' => $password,
        'applicationKey' => $appKey,
    ),
), ['password']))->redact();

$this->logger->debug("REQUEST: URL[{$this->config->endpoint}] BODY: " . json_encode($body));
```

You can redact any array key you wish by providing it in the second constructor argument. In the above example we're only redacting `password`. The package also supports deep-nested keys.