# Remove keys without specified names

Tags: php, arrays, unset

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [44] => 2
    [21] => 2
    [] => 2
    [27] => 2
)
```

How to find and remove (unset) keys without specified names? So in this case array should look like this:

```
Array
(
    [44] => 2
    [21] => 2
    [27] => 2
)
```

Comment: How you add values to the array? all keys need to be name. if you add value as
$array[] = 2
then key will be the next key by count, or 0.

Comment: The key is just `''` no? Create a new array, do a foreach on first array, add value on new array if key is not empty...Maybe there is a php array function but don't know it. And how do you get this value? Can you have multiple empty key?

Comment: @Evgeniy Belov I do not create this array - this is what i get from external source :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Delete an element from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369602/php-delete-an-element-from-an-array)

Comment: A php array cannot have more than one element with the same key.  A single `unset()` is all that is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could be the key is `''`  (empty string)

in this case assuming  you have

```
   $myArray = [
    [44] => 2,
    []   => 2,
    [21] => 2,
    [27] => 2,
   ]
```

then try unset

```
 unset($myArray['']);
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you have an array (key-value)
in this type of arrays we have a key, and its not possible to have a cell without any key.
so as you mentioned in your question, the cell which seem that has not any key, already has the ''(empty string) key. i mean its definition has been like this

```
$array['']=2;
```

so you can simply unset it as normal. like this

```
unset( $array['']);
```

because if you define a cell as bellow:

```
 $array[]=2;
```

automatically it gives the first available numerical key.
for example if you have:

```
 $array[4]=5;
 $array[]=6;
```

it automatically gives the next free index , it means to php like this:

```
 $array[4]=5;
 $array[5]=6;
```

i hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (($key = array_search(null', $array)) !== false) {
    unset($array[$key]);
}
```

I suggest you to read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448964/php-how-to-remove-specific-element-from-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution will be the simplest one:

```
$array = [
44 => 2,
21 => 2,
'' => 2,
27 => 2
];

$results = [];

foreach ($array as $k => $a) {
    if (!empty($k)) {
        $results[$k] = $a;
    }
}

var_dump($results);
```

[sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5d57d23fa605f26b14cf0c367007d9a39d5ade1f)

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

```
$arrayWithoutNullKeyMembers = array_filter($arrayWithNullKeyMembers,
                        function($key){ return !empty($key); }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```